# Expected Value of Symmetric PDF's

Tags: probability

> Note that when the pdf is symmetric at point $m$. That is, if
> $$
> f_X(m-x)=f_X(m+x)
> $$ for all $x$
> then $E[X]=m$

I have trouble analyzing its derivation below:

---

Its construction starts with

$$
0=\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}(m-t)f_X(t)dt
$$
(Why?) Then
$$
m \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}f_X(t)dt-\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}tf_X(t)dt
= m-E[x]=0
$$

That proves it but I am wondering how the first construction is related to the symmetry of the PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty (m-t) f_X(t) dt = \int_{-\infty}^\infty   s f_X(s+m)ds$$
The symmetry assumption means that $s\mapsto s f_X(s+m)$ is an *odd* function. For any odd function $g(s)=-g(-s)$ for which the integral is defined,
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty  g(s) ds = \int_{0}^\infty  g(s) ds + \int_{-\infty}^0  g(s) ds = \int_{0}^\infty  g(s) ds + \int_0^\infty g(-r)dr = 0. $$